# How can I invite a new user to my Bluemix Organization?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to add a user to my Bluemix organization.  When I go to manage my organizations, as the page loads, I see a button to 'Add Users', but then it disappears.

Is there a new way to invite new users?  The Select Users dropdown list doesn't contain the user I want to invite.

Comment: In my Bluemix I have "Manage Organizations". For an org I get a pop-up overlay that has 3 areas to choose: "Users", "Domains", "Quota" - users is shown by default. There is a "Invite a New User" link. When clicked it bring a new overlay windows where you can enter the user data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "Invite a New User" button where the pop-up lets you enter the email address of the user you would like to add. It is found under the "Users" tab in the "Manage Organization" page. Your button may have disappeared because you don't have the proper privilege to add users.

Only the following Bluemix users can invite users to an organization:

- The account owner of the organization
- Organization managers who are also members, not collaborators, of the organization

In Bluemix, you can be either a member or a collaborator of an organization:

- Collaborator: You are a collaborator of an organization if you already have a Bluemix account, and someone else invites you to the organization.
- Member: You are a member of an organization if you don't have a Bluemix account, but then someone invites you to the organization and you sign up for Bluemix from the invitation.

You cannot invite users to your organization if you are a collaborator of the organization, even if you have been assigned as an organization manager.

See this link for more details:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/accessing.html#tr_adduser

Answer (score 1):

If the 'Add User' or 'Invite User' option is disappearing then this means either you are not the organisation owner or you are the organisation owner but you was originally added to that organisation when you already had your own organisation.

In Bluemix a user is either a collaborator or a member. A collaborator is someone that was added to an organisation but previously had they own account/organisation. A member is someone who never had a previous Bluemix account when was added to the organisation.

It is only Organisation managers that are members that can add or invite users. See the doc page [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/troubleshoot/accessing.html#tr_adduser) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As of **August 2017**, the information provided above does not hold (and the documentation link is dead); now, the "Manage Organizations" page does not contain a "Users" tab - only an "Add a New Org" button.

To add a new user to your organization, you should now use the "Manage" tab just under your avatar icon at the top-right screen corner:

[image]

Manage -> Account -> Users will lead you to a Users page, from where you can now invite new users to your organization.